# dx=(x>0)*dout what does x>0 part in this code?

Tags: python, deep-learning, backpropagation, relu

There is python code about Relu backward propagation. and code is like `dx=(x>0)*dout`, what does `x>0` part do? Can anyone explain me this line of code?

Comment: Did you try it in isolation? What did you find out?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You might compare, say, `(True*3)` and `(False*3)`. That said, since `__gt__()` can return objects of *any* type, in isolation, this question isn't amenable to a canonical answer at all.

Comment: Since Python operators can be overloaded, it's impossible to know for certain what the  `>` will do without knowing the type of `x`. However, for most sensible implementations, the result of `(x>0)` will be either `True` or `False`, and in a numeric context `True` has a value of one and `False` has a value of zero.

Answer (score 1):

The Relu function is defined as:  `f(x) = max(0,x)`
It means if `x<=0` then `f(x)=0`, else `f(x)=x`.

So if `x<=0`, `dx=0`, else `dx=dout`.